# How to crash a Linux PC at a specified time?

Tags: shell-script, crash

I am working on a security use case where a linux PC can fall in the hands of an enemy who may gain access to the system (asking password at gun point) etc.
I am looking for a technique (a short script or command) that will crash a linux PC at/after a specified time.  All the data should be lost and the PC should no longer boot. Re-installation of the OS should be the only option left.

EDIT: Just for clarification. I know how to find all files and delete them. I know how to mess with the boot loader. I am just more interested in setting the time factor.

Comment: @Sneetsher:  I have no such intention. I am working on a security use case where a linux PC can fall in the hands of an enemy who may gain access to the system ( asking password at gun point) etc. I cannot reveal more.

Comment: I don't buy it. Question like this shows that you're not the one who should work on such of solution...

Comment: :) Really interesting comments

Comment: This is why we have encrypted filesystems...

Comment: @Michael Homer: Just for clarification. I know how to find all files and delete them. I am just more interested in setting the time factor.

Comment: It turns out that I cannot even delete this question now.

Comment: @pawel7318: You sound condescending.

Comment: @Jay: I just hope in next few years you'll laugh on that question by yourself. I'll tell you way to take - first read about VFS, different filesystems, SSD drives, trimming and write caches to learn what does it really mean to "delete the file". Try to find some info about file descriptors and what happens if process holds some. Than make some tests to find out how much time it's going to take to "find and delete all files". Then setup encrypted filesystem by yourself. After all of it come back and ask your question (don't forget to mention what you've learned). I'm not able to help you more.

Comment: @pawel7318: I am laughing at it right now for getting blown out of proportion.

Comment: @pawel7318: Anyway why should anyone know all these just to delete a file permanently? You could have helped me by writing a few commands instead of a unix book table of contents.

Comment: @Jay: I don't want to fight. I was trying to show you how many things you should be aware of to successfully achieve what you want. Delete the files has nothing to do with safely destroying data. You need to consider time factor as well as someone can simply turn off your system before it perform any action. Learn all of this than you'll find your question doesn't have much sense. Good luck.

Comment: @pawel7318: Does not have much sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

This will overwrite your MBR with (pseudo) random data. At least you'll be sure not to boot your OS again (neither Windows).

dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1

Comment: This doesn't erase data or require re-installation of the OS. It is still, I think, unwise to post.

Comment: @Michael Homer: Come on Michael! Security Through Obscurity never works.

Comment: Of course it does, that's the whole point of one-time pads. My confidence in security through someone who asked this question is, of course, unshaken.

Comment: @Michael : Then why fear?